# How to pass variable in Webdriver-Sampler | Jmeter Webdriver

Tags: variables, selenium, jmeter

I got a Testscript with more than 8 Webdriver-Sampler and a variable, which change in some of the Webdriver-Sampler.

For Example:

**First Sampler:** 
status =     "login successful"

**Second Sampler:**   status = "login successful, search for something failed"

**Third Sampler:** status = "login successful, search for something failed, logout successful"

So I have to pass the variable everytime and then edit this variable. 
I know it is possible to pass a varibale about the Parameter-field. But how can I edit a user define variable in script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance via [JMeterContext.getVariables()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getVariables()) method like:

```
var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
vars.put('foo','bar')
var foo = vars.get('foo')
//etc
```

[image: WebDriver Sampler Demo]

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks

Comment: how can we export a variable from `selenium/webdriver` to another `Selenium/Webdriver` sample ??

Comment: Use vars.put("varName", value) or WDS.vars.put("varName", value) to set variables to be shared across any sampler withing same thread. Use props.put("varName", value) to share values among all threads. You can use vars.get("varName"), props.get("varName") to retrieve the values